# Android: How to update an UI from AsyncTask if AsyncTask is in a separate class?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, updates

I hate inner class.

I've a main activity who launches a 'short-life' AsyncTask.

AsyncTask is **in a separate file**, is not an inner class of main activity

I need async task updates a textView from main Activity.

I know i can update a TextView from onProgressUpdate, if AsyncTask is a inner class

But how from an external, indipendent, async task ?

UPDATE: This looks like working :

In acitivty i call the task

```
backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
backgroundTask.execute();
```

In the constructor i've

```
public BackgroundTask(Activity myContext)
{
    debug = (TextView) myContext.findViewById(R.id.debugText);
}
```

where debug was a private field of AsyncTask.

So onProgressUpdate I can

```
debug.append(text);
```

Thanks for all of you suggestions

Comment: You means that in another class, you want to access UI ?

Comment: Yes. I need to update a TextView from the AsyncTask.

Comment: You can pass Context in your constructor and with casting it to your ActivityClass, you can change textView using runOnUIThread method.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

AsyncTask is always separate class from `Activity`, but I suspect you mean it is in different file than your activity class file, so you cannot benefit from being activity's inner class. Simply pass Activity context as argument to your Async Task (i.e. to its constructor)

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

    WeakReference<Activity> mWeakActivity;

    public MyAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
       mWeakActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
    }

 ...
```

and use when you need it (remember to NOT use in during `doInBackground()`) i.e. so when you would normally call

```
int id = findViewById(...)
```

in AsyncTask you call i.e.

```
Activity activity = mWeakActivity.get();
if (activity != null) {
   int id = activity.findViewById(...);
}
```

Note that our `Activity` can be gone while `doInBackground()` is in progress (so the reference returned can become `null`), but by using `WeakReference` we do not prevent GC from collecting it (and leaking memory) and as Activity is gone, it's usually pointless to even try to update it state (still, depending on your logic you may want to do something like changing internal state or update DB, but touching UI must be skipped).

Comment: If you go this route, it's better to hold the activity reference as a WeakReference<Activity> instead of just Activity. IMO.

Comment: WebnetMobile.com, ah ok, I wasn't sure, good to know. @realtebo, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html

Comment: Holding references to UI elements in AsyncTask is a bad idea. `WeakReference` is better but I recommend @Ams answer which uses an interface for the communication. It depicts loose coupling without any references being held in the AsyncTask itself. Same is taught in Android Developers video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtlRNNhane0&index=4&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE .

Answer (score 26):

Using Interface 
1) Create one Interface

```
public interface OnDataSendToActivity {
    public void sendData(String str);
}
```

2) Implements it in your Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnDataSendToActivity{

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          new AsyncTest(this).execute(new String[]{"AnyData"}); // start your task
     }

     @Override
     public void sendData(String str) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     }

}
```

3) Create constructor in AsyncTask(Activity activity){}
   Register your Interface in AsyncTask file
   and call interface method as below.

```
public class AsyncTest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    OnDataSendToActivity dataSendToActivity;
    public AsyncTest(Activity activity){
        dataSendToActivity = (OnDataSendToActivity)activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dataSendToActivity.sendData(result);
    }

}
```

Here, your OnPostExecute will call after all task done by AsyncTask and will get "result" 
as a parameter, returned by doInBackground(){ return "";}.

While "dataSendToActivity.sendData(result);" it will call activity's overrided method "public void sendData(String str) {}".

An edge case to remember: Be sure to pass `this`, i.e. you current activity's context to `AsyncTask` and not create another instance of your activity, otherwise your `Activity` will be destroyed and new one is created.

Comment: This maybe right at the first glimpse,cannot handle multiple general `AsyncTask` in one Activity.

Comment: This is a good solution. Implementing an interface loosen the coupling and is recommended in this Android Developer video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtlRNNhane0&index=4&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE .

Comment: Doesn't this still keep a reference to the activity? Isn't `dataSendToActivity` just an activity that implements `OnDataSendToActivity`?

Answer (score 5):

Make an static function in your activity class passing context in it to update your text view and then call this function in your AsynkTask class to update.

In Activity class:
public static void updateTextView(){

//your code here
}

In AynckTask class call this function.

Comment: Your TextView would need to be static for that which would be a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the context (activity or whatever) to your AsyncTask in a constructor and then in onSuccess or onProgressUpdate call whatever you need on the context.

Comment: That would cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a small extension to AsyncTask for this kind of scenario. It allows you to keep your AsyncTask in a separate class, but also gives you convenient access to the Tasks's completion:

```
public abstract class ListenableAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>{

    @Override
    protected final void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        notifyListenerOnPostExecute(result);
    }

    private AsyncTaskListener<Result> mListener;
    public interface AsyncTaskListener<Result>{
        public void onPostExecute(Result result);
    }
    public void listenWith(AsyncTaskListener<Result> l){
        mListener = l;
    }
    private void notifyListenerOnPostExecute(Result result){
        if(mListener != null)
            mListener.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

So first you extend ListenableAsyncTask instead of AsyncTask. Then in your UI code, make a concrete instance and set listenWith(...).

Answer (score 2):

The Question has already been answered, still im posting how it should be done i guess..

**Mainactivity class**

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {

        TextView Ctemp;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Ctemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Ctemp);
            doConv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doConv);
            doConv.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) // The conversion to do
        {
            new asyncConvert(this).execute();
        }
    }
```

**now in the async class**

```
public class asyncConvert extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    SoapPrimitive response = null;
    Context context;

    public asyncConvert(Context callerclass)
    {
        contextGUI = callerclass;
    }
.
.
.
.
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        ((MainActivity) contextGUI).Ctemp.setText(result); // changing TextView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
     public  static class updateTExtviewAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        Context context;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        String id, name;

        String state_id;

        //--- Constructor for getting network id from asking method

        public  updateTExtviewAsyncTask(Context context,String id,String city) 
        {
            context   = context;
            state_id  = id;
            city_name = city;
        }       
        /* *
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "","Please wait...", true, true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
        {
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url)  {

                     YourClass.UpdateTextViewData("Textview data");
        }
    }
```

// place this code inside your activity class and also declare updating textview static

```
    public static void  UpdateTextViewData(String tvData) 
{
   tv.setText(tvData);
}
```