# AsyncTask - How to access to GUI elements from OnPostExecute

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application with the following workflow :

Main activity where the user types his research keywords -> Click on the "search" button -> Starting an AsyncTask making a query on a webservice (query handled within the doInBackground method) -> Creation of a new activity.

Now I want to display the webservice result within this new activity. How can I do ? I know I should to use "onPostExecute" but the AyncTask object has not any access to this new Activity from the "onPostExecute" method. Any clues ?

Thank you !

Comment: have a async task in the same activity. asynctask class inside the activity class.

Comment: Or pass whatever view you want to the result to display in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to access to GUI elements from OnPostExecute

Make a activity and get the view in `onCreate(bundle)` and Define a `AsyncTask` as inner class.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{ 
    TextView textView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
         ....
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    }
```

Declare the `AsyncTask` inside this class.

```
   private class UpdateUiAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
      ........
      .....
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      textView.setText(result);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution can cause memory leaks. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252654/android-how-to-update-an-ui-from-asynctask-if-asynctask-is-in-a-separate-class

Comment: you should do the same thing as you do for context which is to pass the view in a WeakReference<View>