# Informationparsing from URL-Request not working / Didn't found TextView

Tags: android, json, url-parsing

i need your help. I want to send a URL Request, get response and create a JSON Object. My first try was totally wrong. Now I found a tutorial and made a new try.

My Activity looks like:

```
public class Patienten extends Activity {

//Beacon Elemente
private String UUID;
private String Major;
private String Minor;

private TextView output;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_patienten);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    UpdateBeaconInformation();

    Button cmdHit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmd_hit);
    cmdHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new JSONTask().execute("//http://kusber-web.de/JsonTest.txt");
        }
    });


    setTitle(Surname + ", " + FirstName);
   // output.setText(output.getText().toString() + "Gefundener Patient:\n" + "Name: " + Surname + ", " + FirstName + "\nGeb.-Dat: " + Birthdate);
}
```

Then I created a new Java Class and built an asyncTask with it. But I can't access to the textview output in onPostExecute to update it.

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {

        //http://kusber-web.de/JsonTest.txt
        //http://nilsbenning.selfhost.me/PatientFinder.php?beacon_comID=5181f8a3-7354-46ac-b22d-952ec395ab06&beacon_major=12&beacon_minor=249
        URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        return buffer.toString();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    output.setText(result);

}
```

}
What is my mistake? Why I can't access to it? I saw it as a solution here but didn't get it to work:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12252717/5743912

Hope you can help me now! :)

Comment: "What is my mistake?" -- among possibly other things, you are doing network I/O on the main application thread, and you are catching exceptions without logging them.

Comment: Ok you're right @CommonsWare . I am sorry I am totally new at android developing. 

I learned much last hours and create a new way. Can you help me to find the mistake now??

Comment: You have // BEFORE http in your URL. Try setting breakpoints inside the exception handlers and the finally clause. That may help you locate the problem.

Comment: @Jim Rhodes Yes the // is for my information. The URL is called as parameter from the .execute...

I can't set a breakpoint there because it's not possible to compile when there is the output.setText within the error. I can't access to the TextView from the Patient Activity in the AsyncTask class. But I don't understand how to work than with this.

How can I get the String which I get as result from the URL connection in AsyncTask to my Patienten Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to fix this (remove leading slashes):

```
new JSONTask().execute("//http://kusber-web.de/JsonTest.txt");
```

In your **JSONTask** you can reference members of **Patienten** by using `Patienten.this`. So in `onPostExecute` you should change this:

```
output.setText(result);
```

to:

```
Patienten.this.output.setText(result);
```

Comment: You are right with the // how silly from me!

Now I get com.projektarbeit.Patienten is not an enclosing class. How to fix it? Should I initiate it in the AsyncTask? Make that sence because Patienten is calling the AsyncTask and then initiate that there??

Comment: @AndroidNewbee You should define your JSONTask as an inner class of Patienten.

Comment: I am really a Newbee :D Never heared from an inner class before. Read it at Google, copy and paste it and it's running!

So easy! With much thanks!!!!